# Microsoft Asset Inventory Service - Userful or not?

Tags: windows

I downloaded MDOP and noticed the AIS portion. I did some research but is anyone using this feature? Is it useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is useful in highly distributed scenarios and when you don't want/can manage on premsie infrastructure like System Center Configuration Manager. Useful as [Windows Intune](http://w.microsoft.com/windows/windowsintune).

The latest version of MDOP  (2011 R2) comes with AIS version 2.0 improved.
You install a little client in your client PCs and they communicate with Microsoft Servers using SSL and report their hardware and software. After that, virtually anywhere you can go to a web site an check the inventory of your machines.

Even more, you can cross your inventory with your Microsoft licensing agreement in the web site and can see easy what you are using, what you are wasting and for what you need to pay.